# Turn off Apache module when on a certain URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I'd like to turn off the pagespeed module for all resources when they're being loaded from a certain page using htaccess.

For example, I want all CSS, images, and JavaScript to be loaded as is without being rewritten by the pagespeed module if the URL is page.php. But I want pagespeed to be enabled for all other URLs.

How can I go about doing this? Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.